# how do i initialize class object before i know the arguments for constructor?

Tags: java

In my assignment i am supposed to create a program that uses a switch case to access methods from a different class to do something. The first case takes in user input, and that input is used in the constructor of the other class. however if i initialize the class object in the first case, i get errors from the other cases because the object may not have been initialized yet. how do i create that object for the class that has my methods, and still get the user input that is prompted in the switch case into the constructor?

```
public class NumberList{

int length; int offset;

     public NumberList(int length, int offset){       //constructor
        this.length = length; this.offset = offset;
     }

     public void shift(int a){                      //shift method
        temp = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++) {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
        }
        numbers[length - 1] = temp;
      }
```

say that is my class with a method to shift array elements. my main method would be

```
public class assignment7{
public static void main(String[] args){

int choice;
do{
System.out.println("input choice");
choice = scan.nextInt();
switch(choice){

        case '1':
            System.out.println("input the array size.");
            size = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("input the array offset.");
            offset = scan.nextInt();
            NumberList numbasbrah = new NumberList(size, offset);
            numbasbrah.printInfo();
            break;
        case '2':
            numbasbrah.shift();
            numbasbrah.printInfo();
            break;
        case '3':     //quit
            break;
}while(choice!=3);
}} //end main method
```

so if i create the NumberList object in the switch case i get the error "variable may not have been initialized" but it needs to be there so i can add the user input for the constructor. how do i initialize the object while still being able to add the information for the constructor in the switch case?

Comment: Is this all the code? How does NumberList compile without any declarations of numbers[] ?

Comment: no i tried to condense... its probably 1/8 of the total code, the actual NumberList has 6 methods in total

Comment: so if the user chooses case 2, what is supposed to be shifted ? will there be default values there?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using numasbrah in case 2 but creating it in case 1.

You have nothing though that is forcing you to go through case 1 before going into case 2.

If someone selects 2 without ever selecting 1 then the program will fail.

There are any number of ways to fix this - including creating a "default" numasbrah outside the switch statement. Probably the simplest though is just to remove the `case 2` completely and run through into it from case 1.

Comment: i have instructions to do it that way! thats why im so confused

Comment: @TylerWeber at start up you should make the user insert the values immediately as the user still has to select case 1 to be able to run the program which leaves case 2 pointless without case 1

Comment: my problem is this is a school assignment that is automatically graded by a computer, that is programmed to start by hitting the first case, then entering the info

Comment: Sounds like a bad assignment. Not that that will get you anywhere. In that case just create a default one outside the switch state (or a null one) as per Eduardo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are instantiating a class inside the case 1 scope, nothing outside of that scope will have access to that object. More information on scopes [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html).

But for your immediate problem if you want the object created in case 1 to be accessible in case 2 just create outside the case but inside the switch (create with default values):

```
switch(choice){

     NumberList numbasbrah =new NumberList(defaultValue, defaultVale);

        case '1':
            System.out.println("input the array size.");
            size = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("input the array offset.");
            offset = scan.nextInt();
            numbasbrah = new NumberList(size, offset);
            numbasbrah.printInfo();
            break;
        case '2':

            numbasbrah.shift();
            numbasbrah.printInfo();

            break;
        case '3':     //quit
            break;
}
```

**NOTE**

The logic here seems faulty. What if user selects case 2, is there going to be a default numbasbrah?

Comment: That will compile but still throw a null pointer exception if they select case 2 first. At the least you should null check the numbasbrah

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an object without creating it, that's all you need to know ! So either you declare it in the switch case not in the the first case, and you must be sure that the user will go for the case one before the case two, or you can add a new boolean variable that tells if the object has been created or not and use it in the cases that uses the object to be sure that it has already been created ! That's what I would have done.

Or use `if(numbasbrah != null)` as Eduardo says

Comment: can you explain how you would use a boolean? and would it allow the program to compile and run whilest keeping the "NumberList numbasbrah = new NumberList(size, offset);" in the first case?

Comment: assign true to a boolean when you create your `NumberList`, and in the 2nd case, add `if(theBoolean)` then do what you need, and in the else statement you say to the user that the object is not created yet

Answer (score 0):

I think switch case is not required here because `case 1` is always required step here .For ex if you define your object as null(as @Eduardo Dennis answer) and then you chosses `case 2` it will give you a null pointer and on the other hand if you chosse `case 1` you are already initializing object so in both cases you need object initialization the why not remove `case 1` and define it outside `switch`or the best is to remove switch and use `if else`